# Output only certain portions of row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file-io

I have this dataframe

```
       X    Y   Z    A
0      1    2   0    4   
1      0    2   3    0 
2      1    0   3    4     
3      1    0   0    4  
4      1    0   0    0
```

I want to save it as a text file with this format (all rows are output but any columns with 0 are excluded)

```
1,2,4
2,3
1,3,4
1,4
1
```

This can be outputted with a for loop but it is very inefficient with a large dataframe. Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [103]: (df.astype(str)
     ...:    .replace('0','')
     ...:    .add(',')
     ...:    .sum(1)
     ...:    .replace([',{2,}',',$','^,'],[',','',''], regex=True))
     ...:
Out[103]:
0    1,2,4
1      2,3
2    1,3,4
3      1,4
4        1
dtype: object
```

Comment: Doesn't using regex just limit you to 2 characters in between the columns?

Comment: Sorry I was just confused by this: replace([r',{2,}',r',$'],[',',''], regex=True)

Is there any way to remove the comma in front of the 2? ",2,3"

Answer (score 2):

`replace` + `str.cat`

```
df.astype(str).replace('0',np.nan).apply(lambda x :x.str.cat(sep=','),1)
Out[525]: 
0    1,2,4
1      2,3
2    1,3,4
3      1,4
4        1
dtype: object
```